# How to make multiple master detail report using SAP crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working in VB.Net 2010 with SQL Server 2014. Using SAP Crystal Reports, I want to make a report in multiple master detail format.

I will explain in detail.

In the Database I have two tables: tbl_Voucher_M and tbl_Voucher_D as master and detail table respectively.
Each voucher consists of one record in its master table (tbl_Voucher_M) and multiple rows in the detail table (tbl_Voucher_M).

Suppose there are 25 vouchers stored in the month of June and I want to make a report that displays all vouchers having their master and detail data one by one vertically for the month of June.
I.e. the report must show the master data of the voucher 1 and then the detail data of voucher 1 and then total of voucher 1, and 
after that .....

The master data of the voucher 2 and then the detail data of voucher 2 and then total of voucher 2, and so on until we get to ......

The master data of the voucher 25 and then the detail data of voucher 25 and then total of voucher 25.

How can I do this?

Comment: " in detail table ( tbl_Voucher_M) " , maybe here it's tbl_Voucher_D ? So you want to display all the unique master row from tbl_Voucher_M , foreach displayed master voucher all the detail row linked to it from tbl_Voucher_D ? So a simple enumeration of master voucher with all his detail rows ?

Comment: Link both the tables and then group by mastar and place detail in detail section